# Why does Wordpress add_menu not work when seperated from Initial plugin page?

Tags: php, wordpress

So I'm working on a very very basic plugin for Wordpress.  I copied the following from the internet a menu item plugin named menu.php

```
<?php

/*
Plugin Name: Test plugin
Description: A test plugin to demonstrate wordpress functionality
Author: Simon Lissack
Version: 0.1
*/
defined( 'ABSPATH' ) or die( 'No script kiddies please!' );

add_action('admin_menu', 'test_plugin_setup_menu');

function test_plugin_setup_menu(){
    add_menu_page( 'Test Plugin Page', 'Test Plugin', 'manage_options', 'test-plugin', 'test_init' );
}

function test_init(){
    echo "<h1>Hello World!</h1>";
}

?>
```

This works as expected but it's a stand alone plugin.  I currently have a different plugin

```
<?php

/*
Plugin Name: My plugin
Description: blah blah
Author: Me
Version: 0.1
*/
defined( 'ABSPATH' ) or die( 'No script kiddies please!' );

fun fun database work on register_activation_hook
?>
```

The problem is I'd like to have it all in one plugin not two I tried this and I deleted the commenting that made it register as a plugin in menu.php

```
/*
Plugin Name: My plugin
Description: blah blah
Author: Me
Version: 0.1
*/
defined( 'ABSPATH' ) or die( 'No script kiddies please!' );

include_once('menu.php');
fun fun database work
?>
```

Fatal error: Call to undefined function wp_get_current_user() in wp-includes\capabilities.php on line 1387 and this is the error I get.  However doing the following gives me the desired result

```
/*
Plugin Name: My plugin
Description: blah blah
Author: Me
Version: 0.1
*/
defined( 'ABSPATH' ) or die( 'No script kiddies please!' );

 add_action('admin_menu', 'test_plugin_setup_menu');

function test_plugin_setup_menu(){
    add_menu_page( 'Test Plugin Page', 'Test Plugin', 'manage_options', 'test-plugin', 'test_init' );
}

function test_init(){
    echo "<h1>Hello World!</h1>";
}

fun fun database work
?>
```

The reason I'd like to know how to get it to work using the include or require or at least know why I can't is because I'm sure my plugin will grow and I would like to have it in a bunch of smaller easier for me to maintain files than one big initial file.

Thank you for your help ohh I've also tried

```
<?php

/*
Plugin Name: My plugin
Description: blah blah
Author: Me
Version: 0.1
*/
defined( 'ABSPATH' ) or die( 'No script kiddies please!' );

  //  add_action('plugins_loaded','load_menu');//didn't work same error
add_action('init','load_menu');//didn't work same error

function load_menu(){
    include_once('menu.php');
 }
fun fun database work
?>
```

Thanks again for any help

Comment: What version of WP is this? :S Try add   `require_once(‘pluggable.php’);` at the top of `wp-includes\capabilities.php` ~ type it, don't copy and paste it from here... will cause a unicode problem.

Comment: I'm using the newest Wordpress but I'm trying to do it in a way that doesn't need altering as then it would defeat the purpose of creating a plug in.  I'm hoping to create something that would work and be distributable.  But thank you for the reply and time you took

Comment: Hello @Roger. Yes, I'm aware of plugin encapsulation. I'm was trying to understand your WP and stack set up because your code works fine and as expected on my system.

Comment: I'm using the newest Wordpress 4.2.3 unaltered.